# Copying object properties to array with an empty body for-in loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-in-loop

`I'm reading 'JavaScript: the definitive guide' and I'm getting hung up on an example:

“you can use code like the following to copy the names of all object properties into an array"

```
var o = {x:1, y:2, z:3};
var a = [], i = 0;
for(a[i++] in o) /* empty */;
```

I don't understand, why does the last line really do anything, without instructions. Why does it fill the array?

Comment: Two comments: 1) if it does what it's intended to do, why bother? 2) This code which every maintainer will immediately cause to jump off the window ...

Comment: Because the `a[i++]` is what each key  of `o` is assigned to. Normally you'd use a variable, but instead you're using Array members. Same operation.

Comment: I just wanna understand, why it works. I have no intention to use it as is. it just looks like as the loop body is empty it shouldn't fill the array, so why does it 'do what it's intended to do'?

Comment: Think about how `for ... in` works. The variable on the left side of `in` is **assigned** a key of the object on each iteration of the loop. It's legal in JavaScript for that to be an object property reference, and the auto-increment of `i` means that on each iteration of the loop there's a **different** property of `a` being assigned a value.

Comment: ...and FWIW, in real code, you'd just use `Object.keys(o)`, which is nearly identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, I'm actually surprised that this code works! Let me just say that I wouldn't recommend using it and would expect this sort of `a[i++]` trickery to show up in ancient C, not in Javascript :)

As for why it works, it has to do with the syntax of the language. The [syntax for a for Loop](http://es5.github.io/#x12.6) is:

```
for ( LeftHandSideExpression in Expression ) Statement
```

A [LeftHandSideExpression](http://es5.github.io/#x11.2) is anything that you can assign to with the `=` operator. In a for loop, usually we just use a [variable identifier](http://es5.github.io/#A.3) as in `for(k in o)` but since `arr[i]` is also a valid LHS expression (you can do `arr[i] =`) we are also allowed to write `for(arr[i] in o)`.

In the end, your loop does something similar to

```
var a=[], i=0;
a[i++] = "x";
a[i++] = "y";
a[i++] = "z";
// in the end, a should be ["x", "y", "z"]
// and i should be 3
```

Comment: Check here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in At each iteration of the loop the LHS expression is assigned a property of the RHS. In this case it's the i+1 element of your array. The fact that the loop has no body doesn't matter to JS and since the array is defined outside the scope of the loop, it and all the elements made by the iterations of the loop are available.

Answer (score 6):

this works because the for loop assigns the values in `o` to the variable left of the `in`.

usually this would be a new variable for use in some function. e.g. `for(var a in o){/* do something with a */}`

In this case it assigns it to `a[i++]` where the `i++` increases by 1 each time

it is also worth pointing out the importance of the `;` in `for(a[i++] in o) /* empty */;`
this closes each iteration of the `for`. Without it the next line/loop (whatever it may be) would be repeated.

Answer (score 1):

That's how [`for in` loops](http://es5.github.io/#x12.6.4) work. You can specify an arbitrary left-hand expression as the reference to assign the keys. Usually it's just a reference to a variable, but you can use a property expression such as `a[i++]` as well.

From the spec:

> 1. …
> 2. Let `lhsRef` be the result of evaluating the `LeftHandSideExpression` (**it may be evaluated repeatedly**).
> 3. Call `PutValue(lhsRef, P)`.
> 4. …

Maybe the code is easier written as

```
for(a[i] in o) i++;
```